# Alexa Account Linking to Azure AD: We were unable to link ... at this time

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to setup an Alexa skill which can authenticate to the Microsoft Active Directory for our Company.

All steps that I followed are described here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/01/25/amazon-alexa-skills-authenticated-by-azure-active-directory-and-backed-by-an-azure-function/

[image]

Comment: were you able to see the login screen of Azure AD before you saw that message, or ended up directly with this error when clicked on "link account"?

Comment: Yes I could login to my Azure Account without any problem. The error seemed to happen on the redirect.